# One word for "easily understood"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a one word substitute for something which is "easily understood"? I can think of *clear* but I guess there are other better words.

*Edit 1.* 
Will the answer be different for *easily understandable*? (As opposed to  *easily understood*)

*Edit 2.* Here's an example to more narrowly indicate the sort of usage desired:

> The manual should be precise and *easily understandable*.

Comment: After your 2nd edit, the words "succinct" and "concise" spring to mind. Not really analogues of "easily understood", but might be worthy of consideration.

Comment: @Reg Wish there was similar protection from misuse of down voting.

Comment: After the edit, I think the concept you are trying to capture is *clarity*, which makes "clear" the simplest and most obvious choice to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the manual is to be easily understandable, so should be this statement, right?

"*The manual should be precise and **easy to understand***" is the best wording.

Comment: It may not be one word, but after examining the whole list of proposals, I think _easy to understand_ is the simplest, clearest, most lucid suggestion. +1.

Answer (score 13):

Try one of these:

> simple
>   comprehensible
>   straight-forward
>   understandable
>   intelligible
>   fathomable
>   graspable

Comment: I'm not a big fan of _graspable_, but there are some worthy candidates in this list.

Answer (score 6):

I like *[lucid](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lucid)* (in sense 1 "clear; easily understood").

Answer (score 2):

**Simple** is the best (and *simplest*) substitute.

> This concept can be easily understood.
>
> This concept is simple.

Answer (score 2):

The expression I might use is **self-evident.**

Answer (score 2):

**Clear**: meaning easy to perceive, understand, or interpret. Evident.
In your example:

> The manual should be precise and easily understandable.
>
> The manual should be precise and *clear*.

Answer (score 1):

How about *[coherent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coherent)*?

> b : having clarity or intelligibility : understandable
>
> Examples: *a coherent
>   person; a coherent passage*

Comment: @cornbread...please see my edits. I am overwhelmed by the ocean of words. Of course I did not provide the context/example earlier.

Comment: I stand by *coherent*.  'Easily understandable' is in the M-W definition I quoted.

Answer (score 1):

> **accessible** [- easily understood or appreciated.](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accessible)

Answer (score 0):

You could go with:

The manual should be precise and *user-friendly*.

It is a familiar term now and, of course, means easy to understand and easy to use.