# I need a word that means "easily understood or relatable to the common man"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I can't think of a word that would summarize this phrase into one coherent adjective. It's for a thesis I'm writing about a musical composer.

Comment: Related: [One word for "easily understood"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/66281/48426)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's [perspicuous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perspicuous):

> Clearly expressed or presented; easy to understand

You'd definitely get points for using a difficult word to mean easily understood!  I'd recommend:

- clear
- clear-cut
- comprehensible
- explicit
- intelligible
- straightforward

Of which I personally prefer `straightforward`.

Comment: *Perspicuous* pretty much [fell into disuse in the 1800s](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perspicuous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), probably because of confusion with *perspicacious*. In some (particularly, *earlier*) contexts, the two words are effectively synonymous anyway.

Comment: +1 for "comprehensible", which seems to fit the request best for me.

Answer (score 3):

> **accessible** [- easily understood or appreciated.](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accessible)

Comment: Answered before seeing the Dup link (which I've now endorsed with a closevote here), so I've copied this answer against the earlier question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a term, used especially in connection with complex or technical material that may suit: *[user-friendly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/user-friendly)*

> easy to use or understand

Comment: Do you refer to music as user-friendly?

Comment: @user814064 I think you could refer to almost anything that has the potential to be complex as *user-friendly*. If you were discussing an opera to someone who was not familiar with the form, it could be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with 'easily understood'? 'Lucid' could be a possibility in the right context. As far as 'relating to the common man', you could say that something was 'an everyday expression' or something that would be understood by 'the person in the street'. If you used 'perspicuous' in an undergraduate essay the tutor marking would probably not know what it meant and would have to stretch for a dictionary. It is a fine line between using expressive language and using over-flamboyant or slightly archaic language. 'Perspicuous' clearly falls in the latter category, in my view.